# What are the 3 flavours in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: release-management

I can find these 3 flavours on Ubuntu download page, but previously, I could find only 32 and 64 bit versions. Can anybody explain about each?

1. 64-bit
2. 32-bit (for machines with less than 2GB RAM)
3. 64-bit Mac (AMD64)

Note: I have i5-4Gb system.

Comment: @Rinzwind There is a 2 GB barrier based on addresses >= 0x80000000 (2 GiB) being reserved for the kernel, causing RAM above that address to become unaddressable. I don't recall whether i386 Linux uses 0x80000000, 0xC0000000 (3 GiB) or even 0xE0000000 (3.5 GiB) as the cutoff point, but some degree of address space needs to be reserved for kernel use. Same reason why 32-bit Windows has a /3GB boot switch, moving the cutoff point from 2 GiB to 3 GiB.

Answer (score 3):

1. First option is for modern machines with more than 4 GB of RAM. The processor must support 64 bit mode.
2. It's for older machines. Suitable for all Intel and AMD processors, but leaks with performance.
3. It is designed for Apple Mac computers in case of first option not working.

If your computer isn't a Mac, choose the first one.

Comment: is there any software demand for 64 os

Answer (score 1):

A better explanation is on http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/

**PC (Intel x86) desktop image**

> For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.

**64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image**

> Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead.

**64-bit Mac (AMD64) desktop image**

> Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead. This image is adjusted to work properly on Mac systems.